# Error 404 on any secure pages!

Tags: magento-1.7

We had a problem with our VPS and when we try to get in any pages using SSL, since the SSL hasn't been re-installed, we have a default ssl certificate which is not trusted. Could it be the cause of the Error 404 problem I am getting at:

https://www.naturalscents.ca/index.php/customer/account/login/

?

This matter is really urgent. Also if you think it is something else or you need any more information please ask me!

Answer (score 1):

Check your database table core_config_data.

Under the column "path" search for "web/secure/base_url". Ensure the value in that is https://www.naturalscents.ca/